# mvc 1.0 and DLL location

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[Scott](http://media.wiley.com/assets/1539/15/professionalaspnet35mvc_chapter13.pdf) says we need these 3 DLLs in our BIN folder:
1 - System.Web.Abstractions.dll, 
2 - System.Web.Mvc.dll, and 
3 - System.Web.Routing.dll

I installed the [AspNetMVC1.msi](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en) on Windows 2008 x64 and found this file but the others seem to be missing in action. Any ideas?

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll and xml but the other 2 are hiding somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other files are part of SP1 of the .NET Framework.

They are in the directory C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\

They are also registerd with the gac when you install sp1.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick response. Guess there isn't much point puttin them in the BIN if v3.5 is required in the first place.